# selecting rows with condition in data table R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a data table as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(ID = rep(c('A','B','C'),3), Month = rep(c(1,2,3),3),
             Tier = c(rep('Reg',3),'Reg','Reg','Late',rep('Reg',3)))
```

I want to select the `IDs` that in certain months (in this case let's say all of `months 1, 2, and 3`) have the `Tier` value of `Reg`. So in this example it should only return IDs `A` and `B`, whose `Tier` is `Reg` in all the `Month`. It seems to be simple but I am somehow stuck. I tried:

```
unique(DT[Month %in% c(1,2,3) & Tier == 'Reg',ID])
```

But it returns `A,B,C`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your description of what is wanted the result A,B,C seems correct.

Comment: @IRTFM ID `C` should not be selected since in `Month 3`, the `Tier` is not `Reg`.

Comment: ID C has Tier == "Reg" in the third and ninth line of DT

Comment: @IRTFM selected `IDs` should have `Tier` equal to `Reg` in all months (edited the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
DT[,.(select=all(Tier=='Reg')),by=ID][select==T,ID]

[1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: It seems to get the job done. However, I am wondering if this can be done by `&` `|` statements?!

Comment: I don't think so because `&` `|` statements apply only to the row, whereas you need here a `group by` to check all months for one `ID`

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your needs?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID = rep(c('A','B','C'),3), Month = rep(c(1,2,3),3),
                 Tier = c(rep('Reg',3),'Reg','Reg','Late',rep('Reg',3)))

DTX <- DT[, .(KEEP = length(unique(Tier)) == 1), by = ID]
DTX
#>    ID  KEEP
#> 1:  A  TRUE
#> 2:  B  TRUE
#> 3:  C FALSE
DTX[KEEP == TRUE, ID]
#> [1] "A" "B"
```

In case you want to manipulate your data for one case only, replace `.` by `:=`.